# Internationalization - how to handle gender?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I have a cakephp 3 application I'm currently internationalizing. The app is written in french, I'm adding english.

I'm using the built in tools of cakephp 3 to do it. There is a sentence in my app that must be translated differently in english whether the user is a man or a woman. In french, the sentence remains the same.

French sentence: "xxx n'a pas indiqué ses disponibilités"

English translation: "xxx did not give his availabilities" for a man, "xxx give her availabilities" for a woman.

At first, my app looked like this:

```
<?= __("{0} n'a pas indiqué ses disponibilités", $user->name); ?>
```

I changed it so that two different translations could be provided:

```
<?php if ($user->gender == 'M'): ?>
<?= __("{0} n'a pas indiqué ses disponibilités", $user->name); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?= __("{0} n'a pas indiqué ses disponibilités", $user->name); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when generating the pot file with `bin/cake i18n extract` only one sentence was extracted. I've then tried this:

```
<?php if ($user->gender == 'M'): ?>
<?= __x("speaking of a man", "{0} n'a pas indiqué ses disponibilités", $user->name); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?= __x("speaking of a woman", "{0} n'a pas indiqué ses disponibilités", $user->name); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Still, only one msgid is recorded in the pot file. How to handle this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the context translation function is the way to go, your last example is the correct way of handling such cases.

The problem is the I18N shells extract task, it uses only the message as the identifier to store the extracted values, resulting in the previous contexts to be overwritten. I would consider this to be a bug, please [**report it over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

Until this is fixed you'll have to manually add the missing messages to your `.pot` file.

Comment: I was using __x() for the first time. Not sure if I was misusing it or if it was a bug. Thanks for your answer, i'm reporting it.